# Can't decode from windows1252 to UTF8

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8

I know questions about encoding and decoding in utf-8 have been asked so many times, but I could not find an answer to my question.
I have a CSV file in `windows1252` and I want to make it in `UTF-8`, here is the script:

```
import os
import sys
import inspect
import codecs
import chardet
from bs4 import UnicodeDammit

#Declare the variables
defaultencoding = 'utf-8'
filename = '19-01-2017+06-00-00.csv'


#open the file and get the content
file_obj = open(filename,"r")
content = file_obj.read()
file_obj.close()

#Check the initial encoding using both unicodeDammit and chardet
dammit = UnicodeDammit(content)
#print it
print(dammit.original_encoding)
print(chardet.detect(content)['encoding'])


#Decode in UTF8
content_decoded = content.decode('windows-1252')
content_encoded = content_decoded.encode(defaultencoding)
#Write the result in a temporary file
file_obj = open('tmp.txt',"w")
try:
    file_obj.write(content_encoded)
finally:
    file_obj.close()
#Read the result decoded file
file_obj = open('tmp.txt', "r")
content = file_obj.read()
file_obj.close()

#Check if it is really in UTF8 using both unicodeDammit and chardet
dammit = UnicodeDammit(content)
print(dammit.original_encoding)
print(chardet.detect(content)['encoding'])
```

> **Output:**

```
windows-1252
windows-1252
windows-1252
windows-1252
```

Expected output:

```
windows-1252
windows-1252
utf-8
utf-8
```

I used `chardet` and `uncodeDammit` because I found out that `chardet` is not giving the correct encoding guess all the time.

Why can't encode the file in utf-8 ?

Comment: try passing passing `encoding='utf8'` to `open` if you are on Python 3. Also, you should be using files in a `with` block, not with `try except`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm using python 2.7. I switched to with.

Comment: Both `chardet` and `UnicodeDammit` only make educated guesses about the encoding, they wont't be right in every case. Specially if the original data contains only a few bytes outside the ascii range and those are ambiguous. They don't tell you what the encoding _is_ but what it _might be_, chardet also gives you a `confidence` how likely it thinks its guess is, you should also print that.

Comment: @mata `confidence` value is `0.73` . Is there any other alternative to use so that I can get UTF-8 in the output? I need it for a unittest of my check_encoding function. As long as I don't get utf8 the unittest fails and says that `self.assertEqual(encoding,DEFAULT_ENCODING)
AssertionError: 'windows-1252' != 'utf-8'
`

Comment: It's not safe to read / write non-ASCII files in Python 2 in text mode, you should be opening those files in binary mode. And rather than relying on software to guess the encoding try to find out what encoding was actually used to write your source file. You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: Also, to use the `print` function in Python 2 you need `from __future__ import print_function`. Otherwise, you're merely using the `print` _statement_ with a tuple.

Comment: @Somar: You could still follow juanpa's advice by using [the `io` module, whose `io.open` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) is equivalent to Python 3's built-in `open` even on Python 2 (on Python 3, they're aliases for one another). It would simplify your code to just a pair of `io.open` calls (using `with` statement) and an `shutil.copyfileobj` call to copy the data, which would be seamlessly transcoded as it went.

Comment: Good call, @ShadowRanger I keep forgetting that you can pass an encoding arg to `io.open` even in Python 2. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you guys I used this `codecs.open(filename, encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')` and if the file is invalid ut8 it gives error otherwise it prints utf8 :-)

Comment: @Somar: Please use `io.open`, not `codecs.open`. The latter is broken for line ending conversions on text files, the former is not. The former is also slightly faster IIRC. `codecs.open` is just plain inferior, and should be treated as deprecated.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Done and it works! Thanks a lot